# Name of this probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

I want to name a process in which I have N = 100 individuals, and each independently has a probability p = 0.2 of an event occurring.

The binomial distribution measures the probability of having n successes in this experiment. But does the probability distribution of the experiment have a name, regardless of the number of successes? It couldn't be uniform, because even if all the probabilities are equal, the sum of the probabilities is greater than 1, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are unhappy with the binomial distribution? That seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are unhappy to have no information on the distribution of the ouputs themself if individual are ordered ? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, if individuals are ordered, the output of my experiment is the indices of individuals that have success.

Comment: Each individual's success has a Bernoulli distribution.  If you want to maintain the identity of the successful individuals then this has a multivariate Bernoulli distribution on $\{0,1\}^N$ while the number of successes has a binomial distribution on $0,1,2,\ldots,N$

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use your proposal.